# TCP C# Packet to Specific Client

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm programming a TCP Server to improve my knowledge about this protocol. Recently, a comunity member (mr. René Vogt) helper me to stablish a connection between my server and multiple clients.

Everything works well and the answer (a simple alive packet) is being sent to all clients connected. But now, I'd like to specify a connection to send the packet. I will give a short explain:

*The server is running in a dedicated host. My personal computer connects to the Server as Client1, sending an alive packet ("AA") and receiving the server reply. Then, another client (Client2, client3... and on) connects to the server. The alive will be received and server will answer to this client. But in addition, I'd like to send a packet like "Client2 is connected" (or anything else) to Client1.*

My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(50000);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");

        counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    //Class to handle each client request separatly
    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;

        string clNo;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
        {
                this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
                this.clNo = clineNo;
                Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
                ctThread.Start();

        }
        private void doChat()
        {
            bool LoopReceive = true;
            bool LoopSend = false;
            int requestCount = 0;
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[256];
            string dataFromClient = null;
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            string serverResponse = null;
            string rCount = null;
            requestCount = 0;
            string Packettosend = "";

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Flush();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

                    Console.WriteLine(" >> PACKET: " + dataFromClient);



                    if (dataFromClient.StartsWith("AA")
                    {
                        Packettosend = "ALIVE";
                        Console.WriteLine("::ALIVE PACKET");
                    }


                    //PACKETS TO SEND
                    if (Packettosend == "ALIVE")
                    {
                        Byte[] sendBytes1 = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
                        networkStream.Write(sendBytes1, 0, sendBytes1.Length);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for some answers, but they didn't work. Is it possible to point the networkstream to anything else than the current client who is sending the packet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No.  Not on same connection.  Your code is sending data at the data layer of the Network.  You could write an application layer that process commands like "Send Message to Client2", "List Current Connections", "Is Clinet2 Connected".  The server would then process commands and send back responses.

Comment: But how to? I'm a beginner and a simple example will be great, if possible, sure.

Comment: The code is not simple.  Best way of learning is to read books to understand basic principals of "Network Communications" and "7 Network Layers".  Most of the code I see posted on line do not understand basic Communication Theory and don't properly separate code into the proper layers.  I have an BSEE in Electrical Engineer, an MSCS in Computer Science, 24 credits towards PhD, and 40 years of on job experience.  I could write the book and teach the course.  But not give a simple example.

Comment: Nobody else? :(

Answer (score 1):

The simple Code is, store client to client list with id or dictionary,

```
Dictionary<TcpClient, int> clintlist= new Dictionary<TcpClient, int>();
```

and when you want to 
send specific client just search for the id on the clientlist